# Include Buttons and Paginator in the Material Table Footer

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material, angular-material-table

I use Angular Material Table and I need a command button and the table's paginator in the table's footer row, something like this
[image]

My code is like this actually

```xml
<div class="example-table-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
    <!-- DataSource's displayedColumns -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <!-- Exporter column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="exporter">
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="exportCsv(dataSource)">
          <i class="material-icons" title="Exporter en CSV">save_alt </i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Paginator column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="paginator">
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="3">
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['exporter', 'paginator']"></tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

As you can see, I moved the `<mat-paginator>` element inside a `td`... But this broke the paginator as it doesn't paginate the table anymore... (you see "0 of 0" and disable pagination buttons)... when I put it back outside the `table` element, the paginator returns to normal...

How to correctly put the paginator inside the footer row?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Finally, I used a toolbar, if someone has the same problem:

```xml
  </table>

  <mat-toolbar>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <mat-icon (click)="exportCsv(dataSource)" title="Export as CSV">save_alt</mat-icon>
      <span class="example-spacer"></span>
      <mat-paginator class="paginator" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>

</div>
```

that gave: 
[image]

Comment: @JCAguilera The `span` tag with the custom class `example-spacer` between the `mat-icon` and `mat-paginator` is doing the trick. You can put `fxFlex: 1 1 auto` in that class to make it work, or simply use `<span fxFlex></span> before the thing you want to shift to the right.

Comment: .mat-toolbar-row{
  justify-content: space-between;
}

This will also do the trick.  No need for example-spacer

Answer (score 0):

There you go, with paginator as sticky footer:

Note: the idea is to put a footer-cell for only one column (here we take the first) and then define a colspan taking full width.

```html
<div class="example-table-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
    <!-- DataSource's displayedColumns -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="20" when="column == displayedColumns[0]">
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="[displayedColumns[0]]; sticky: true"></tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use FlexBox. To make the example easier, it is shown with Bootstrap

```html
<div
      class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row"
      [hidden]="dataSource && dataSource?.data?.length == 0"
    >
      <button
        (click)="onClickAdd()"
        mat-raised-button
        color="primary"
        class="align-self-center"
        type="button"
        *ngIf="selection?.selected?.length !== 0"
      >
        Add all selected
      </button>
      <mat-paginator
        class="ml-auto"
        [length]="totalRows"
        [pageSize]="tableInitPageSize"
        [pageSizeOptions]="tablePageSizeOptions"
      >
      </mat-paginator>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem by assigning the `paginator` of my data source in `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.tableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

By adding width:100% in mat-paginator you will get this design.
example:  .

Comment: please edit your answer, is not really clear what do you try to say, about what style are you talking? the OP asking how to put paginator in the footer row, you explain how to fit the paginator to full container width.